# Installation issues with react-awesome-loaders

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I am facing this issue, after installing npm i react-awesome-loaders:[react-awesome-loaders module is not getting installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcsZB.png)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.